# Is that sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, grammaticality, will-would

I came across the sentence below:

”Honestly, I thought everything went wrong and I will have to take the test again.”

Or should it be written this way:

”Honestly, I thought everything went wrong and I WOULD have to take the test again.”

What's the difference? Are the both sentences correct?
Thanks, Emilia

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct with the right pretext.

> ”Honestly, I thought everything went wrong and I will have to take the test again.”

This could be interpreted as the speaker saying to a friend. They thought everything went wrong, whether it did or not is unimportant, and they have to take the test again, maybe they are required to or want to.

> ”Honestly, I thought everything went wrong and I would have to take the test again.”

This implies that the speaker thought everything went wrong, but actually didn't, and at that moment thought they would have to take the test again.

Comment: +1, but a distinction needs to be made that in the first one that the speaker will have to take the test in the future regardless.